# how to printf in oracle stored procedure (for debugging purposes)?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to debug a stored procedure (Oracle). I want to print some variables.

I don't know what the command to print is (or where to find it). Can anyone tell me what it is?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

This is my trigger:

```
create or replace
procedure bns_saa_confs_update_state (
  theID in varchar2
)
AS
begin
  UPDATE BNS_SAA_CONFIRMATIONS SET SentToWssStatus='T' WHERE ID=theID;
  commit;
end;
```

I want to print theID

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the `dbms_output.put_line()` function:

```
declare
    my_var varchar2(20);
begin
    my_var := 'Hello World';
    dbms_output.put_line(my_var);
end;
/
```

Make sure you have `set serveroutput on` if running from SQLPlus, or set output on if running from an IDE. Some developers will create a wrapper function to simplify debugging.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want the `DBMS_OUTPUT` package, i.e.

```
DECLARE
  a INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Starting value: ' || a );
  a := a + 1;
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Ending value: ' || a );
END;
```

Note that you generally need to enable `DBMS_OUTPUT` in your client application before the data will be displayed.  In SQL*Plus, you'll need to

```
set serveroutput on;
```

before executing the stored procedure in order for data to be displayed after execution.  Other GUI tools have different approaches to enabling `DBMS_OUTPUT`.